# search dynamically created row and delete

Tags: jquery, dom, html-table

I am trying to search a particular row having `userName` which is created dynamically by another function and remove it from the table.But I am now able to search the row.
This is how I am adding a new row:

```
$("table").append("<tr><td>" + userName + "</td></tr>");
```

and this is how I am searching the table for the row having `userName` and removing it:

```
$("table").find("<tr><td>" + userName + "</td></tr>").remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `find` is a selector, not HTML.

```
$("table").find("td:contains("+userName+")").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `contains()` based selector

```
$('table td:contains('+userName+')').remove()
```

or

```
$('table').find('td:contains('+userName+')').remove()
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/047g47n1/)

Your code was not the right way to find existing DOM children.

For exact match use `.filter()`,

```
$("table td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === userName;
}).remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `contains()` function in selector, see below sample code

```
$("table").find("tr > td:contains('"+ userName +"')").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you try with jQuery closest.

```
$('table').closest('tr').remove();
```